# Counting key frequency and create list associated to that key

Tags: python, list

I'd like some help to count frequency of a key and also list some unique data associated with that key.

Imagine input file csv like this:

```
key1, owner1, owner2

key2, ownerA, ownerB
key2, ownerB, ownerB

key3, ownerJ, ownerK
key3, ownerJ, ownerK
key3, ownerL, ownerM
```

I'd like the output csv to be:

```
key   | Freq | List of owners with duplicates removed
key3,    3,    ownerJ, ownerK, ownerL, ownerM
key2,    2,    ownerA, ownerB
key1,    1,    owner1, owner2
```

I've written code to accomplish the frequency count.
But I don't know how to create the list of unique owners?
Here is my code so far in python:

```
import csv
import collections

multiOwner = collections.Counter()

with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        multiOwner[row[0]] += 1

    print ("\n".join(str(element_and_count) 
           for element_and_count in multiOwner.most_common()))
```

How can I build the list of owners and keep it associated with the right key?

Comment: It is unclear how you arrive to the list of owners removed. What exactly is the rule here, you never stated that. Why are ownerL and ownerM removed for example, they occur only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested dictionaries, and a `set` for the owners to remove duplicates. You can use `defaultdict()` to initialize the data for each key.

```
import csv
import collections

multiOwner = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'freq': 0, 'owners': set()}

with open('input.csv', newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for key, owner1, owner2, *_ in csv_reader:
        multiOwner[key]['freq'] += 1
        multiOwner[key]['owners'].add(owner1)
        multiOwner[key]['owners'].add(owner2)
```

Comment: I love it when you get a good use case for defaultdict. Very elegant. To nitpick ever so slightly, you [should use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id1) the `newline=""` argument when opening the file to make sure that newline characters are handled correctly.

Comment: Looks very elegant. I have more fields in the row that I didn't show in my example. How do I specify that key is the first field in the row, and owners are the 2nd and 3rd fields in the row?

Comment: Much appreciated! I've also added lines to print this out in case this is helpful to anyone :
for key in multiOwner:
        print (key, '->', multiOwner[key])